# Files number not counting properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, increment

I have a directory with **264420** files

```
$ find /Users/Username -type f | wc -l
    264420
```

I'm trying to count the file number recursively in Node.js with simple `counter++`

The issue is that `counter++` gives incorrect number of files, while `array.push(file)` with `array.length` in the end working just fine and gives back correct amount of files - **264420**

```
$ node total-files.js

114 'total_files_count' 
264420 'total_files_array_count'
```

The simplified script looks like the following:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const dir = '/Users/Username'
let totalFiles = 0
let totalFilesArray = []

const totalFilesObj = getFilesRecursively(dir, totalFiles, totalFilesArray)

console.log(totalFilesObj.total_files, 'total_files_count', totalFilesObj.total_files_array.length, 'total_files_array_count')


function getFilesRecursively(dir, totalFiles, totalFilesArray){

    totalFiles = totalFiles || 0
    totalFilesArray = totalFilesArray || []  

    try { var files = fs.readdirSync(dir) }
    catch(err) { console.error(err.message)  }

    for (var i in files) {

        var name = path.join(dir, files[i])

        try {  

            let stats = fs.lstatSync(name)  // track symlink as link, but not as file

            if (stats.isDirectory()) 
                getFilesRecursively(name, totalFiles, totalFilesArray) 

            else if (stats.isFile()) {
                totalFiles++   // why this not working? so we should use .push to array instead?
                totalFilesArray.push(name) 
            }

        } catch(err) { console.error(err.message) }     
    }

    return { "total_files" : totalFiles, "total_files_array" : totalFilesArray }
}
```

I'm planning to run the script on large directories with hundreds of thousands of files and want to use counter incremental which is faster than pushing to array.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons

- You are not adding the return value of recursion to the final value.
- And incrementing a primitive value doesn't change the value back in the caller function's scope.

Make it

```
if (stats.isDirectory()) 
{
     var returnVal  = getFilesRecursively(name, totalFiles, totalFilesArray);
     totalFiles +=  returnVal.total_files;
}
```

Also, **set the `totalFiles` value to 0** in the beginning of the method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried what you suggested   `if (stats.isDirectory()) { var a = getFilesRecursively(name, totalFiles, totalFilesArray);  totalFiles += a.total_files }` but this seems to increment number to very large amount. I got `3.5198946802191126e+90 'total_files_count'`

Comment: ohh, can you reset the `totalFiles`  value in the beginning of function. I will update the answer as well.

Comment: ah, you are right! with resettings `totalFiles` its working nicely. will this approach be more efficient in terms of speed / resources on large datasets than `.push`?

Comment: @SystemsRebooter Unless you also want to return the file names, I don't see why `push` is required at first place.

Comment: There is some underlying logic so I will definitely need to think this over. I already have one idea how to reimplement this.

Answer (score 0):

As [@gurvinder372](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984039/gurvinder372) kindly suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48378462/4537590)

> And incrementing a primitive value doesn't change the value back in
>   the caller function's scope.

So one of the possible solutions without changing underlying code logic and not using `.push` is to create single value array and increment that value:

```
totalFiles++                  ->  totalFiles[0]++
let totalFiles = 0            ->  let totalFiles = [0]
totalFiles = totalFiles || 0  ->  totalFiles = totalFiles || [0]
```