# fs.readdirSync freezes Electron application

Tags: node.js, electron

Calling `fs.readdirSync` in recursive manner from renderer process freezes the application.

This happens with latest Electron `1.7.9` on `macOS 10.12.6` and `Windows 10`

**STR:**

- Run following function from devtools and try to click via electron application

> change `dir` with some large directory which contains many files, so
>   function run for some time

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

var dir = '/Users'
var totalFiles = [0]
var filesArray = []
var sizesArray = []


function getFilesRecursively(dir, totalFiles, filesArray, sizesArray){

  try { var files = fs.readdirSync(dir); }
  catch(err) { } // 'fs.readdirSync(dir) -', console.warn(err.message)  }

  for(var i in files){

    var name = path.join(dir, files[i])

    try {  

        let stats = fs.lstatSync(name)  // track symlink as link, but not as file

        if (stats.isDirectory())
            getFilesRecursively(name, totalFiles, filesArray, sizesArray) 


        // filtering out symlinks, sockets etc    
        else if (stats.isFile()) {

            // we can't use regular counter, since incrementing a primitive value doesn't change the value back in the caller function's scope.
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48378462/4537590
            totalFiles[0]++  

            // filtering out 0 size files
            if (stats.size > 0) {   
                sizesArray.push(stats.size)
                filesArray.push(name) 
            }
        } 

        } catch(err) { } // console.warn('fs.lstatSync(name) -', err.message) }   

    }

    console.log(filesArray.length) // console logging to see function progress
    return { "files" : filesArray, "sizes" : sizesArray, "total_files" : totalFiles }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////

getFilesRecursively(dir, totalFiles, filesArray, sizesArray)
```

I've tested this on [Electron API Demos](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos) app as well which uses `"electron": "~1.6.2"` It also freezes.

Kindly help

Comment: It's a synchrone operation, it's normal readSync takes the hand while it's processing.

Comment: as commented above, you are doing sync jobs recursively and it is expected to blocking while doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's the response answering your question, I rewrite my comment:

As explained in the doc, [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) is a synchronous operation, it's normal it takes the hand and block the rest of your application while it's processing.

If you want to avoid this, you'll have to use the asynchronous method [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) instead, with a callback called when ready, or "promisify" it with bluebird or by wraping it into a promise.